# Java Http request: The type java.net.http.HttpResponse$ResponseInfo cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, http

I am trying to create a http request using the httpclient api.
my code looks somewhat like this:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(new URI("http://localhost:8000/get"))
            .header("header1", "value1")
            .header("header2", "value2")
            .GET()
            .build();
HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

however this throws an error, saying : `The type java.net.http.HttpResponse$ResponseInfo cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files`. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using VS Code?